# Html Agility Pack + Get specific node

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-agility-pack

Hello i have a problem with my application.
I need to pick out a specific text between two nodes.

The html page looks like this

```
<td align="right" width="186">Text1</td>
<td align="center" width="51">? - ?</td>
<td width="186">Text2</td>`
```

I can pick out Text1 and Text2 with:

```
HtmlNodeCollection cols = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@width='186']");<br />
foreach (HtmlNode col in cols)<br />
{
    if (col.InnerText == "Text1")
    {
        Label1.Text = col.InnerText;            
    }
}
```

The reason why i have the if-condition is because there are more td's in the page. And i need to specifically pick out the one who got "Text1" in it.

But the problem is how i can parse out the text "? - ?" There are more text in the document also having the text "? - ?" but i need to pick out specifically the one between my two other nodes..

The result should be Text1 ? - ? Text2 etc..

I guess it has something to do with nextchild or sibling etcetera?

Comment: Please format your code by indenting it with four spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check `col.NextSibling.InnerText`.

Comment: fantastic, have been trying to fix this for 2-3 hours :P.. Thanks alot SLaks

Comment: Yes, it's done. I will definitly use this site for more questions :)

Comment: Feel free! :-) In the future, you should format your code by indenting it with four spaces.  (or clicking the `{ }` button in the editor toolbar)

Comment: Yes, i noticed it when i wrote my html. But i didn't know it would also do automagic indenting :).. I think Kobi worked some magic on my post though